Solutions to the PDE $g(x,y)f(x,y)+\partial_x\partial_y f(x,y) = c$?
I would like to solve
$g(x,y)f(x,y)+\partial_x\partial_y f(x,y) = c$,
where $g(x,y)$ is continuous in both variables and infinitely differentiable everywhere except for a finite set of points and $c\in\mathbb{R}$.
Does this PDE have any known solutions, maybe in terms of integrals of $g(x,y)$? The generality of $g(x,y)$ invalidates most of the techniques I know.

How did this arise for you?

I'm investigating a particular differential operator (related to topological supersymmetry in stochastic processes), which I require to be nilpotent. This is the case if and only if the function $f(x,y)$, which represents the coefficient function of a term in the operator, obeys the PDE I'm asking about. I'd like to know what the possible coefficient functions are, so I can understand the conditions for which the operator is nilpotent.

Even second-order ODEs with non-constant coefficients cannot be solved in general, hence PDEs a fortiori. Which kind of $g$ do you intend to consider ?
